# Update a date in an onclick event of a filedownload

Tags: date, download, html-table

I wish to update a field in a table with the current date when a user downloads a file, so I can have a table header 'Last downloaded'

Answer (score 0):

Have the file downloaded via a page which takes the file name as an argument in the query string and updates the database table before returning the file in the response.

Take care to validate what's being downloaded first!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Better to post a ajax call. when user click download link ,You should pass the details through a ajax POST as an XML. Using this xml you can update whtever you want.

Hope this will help you. (..)

Comment: The Ajax call sounds good, I would really appreciate some code snippet?